# How to convert in file csv date in specific column to unix date

Tags: date, awk, sed, cut

I have a file csv with this columns:

```
"Weight","Impedance","Units","User","Timestamp","PhysiqueRating"
"58.75","5.33","kg","7","2020-7-11 19:29:29","5"
```

Of course, I can convert the date command:
`date -d '2020-7-11 19:29:29' +%s`

Results:
1594488569

How to replace this date in csv file in bash script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `GNU sed`

```
sed -E '2,$ s/(("[^"]*",){4})("[^"]+")(.*)/echo \x27\1"\x27$(date -d \3 +%s)\x27"\4\x27/e'
```

- `2,$` to skip header from getting processed
- `(("[^"]*",){4})` first four columns
- `("[^"]+")` fifth column
- `(.*)` rest of the line
- `echo \x27\1"\x27` and `\x27"\4\x27` preserve first four columns and rest of line after fifth column, along with adding double quotes to result of date conversion
- `$(date -d \3 +%s)` calling shell command with fifth column value

Note that this command will fail if input can contain single quotes. That can be worked around by using `s/\x27/\x27\\&\x27/g`.

You can see the command that gets executed by using `-n` option and `pe` flags

```
sed -nE '2,$ s/(("[^"]*",){4})("[^"]+")(.*)/echo \x27\1"\x27$(date -d \3 +%s)\x27"\4\x27/pe'
```

will give

```
echo '"58.75","5.33","kg","7","'$(date -d "2020-7-11 19:29:29" +%s)'","5"'
```

---

For `58.25,5.89, kg, 7,2020 / 7/12 11:23:46, "5"` format, try

```
sed -E '2,$ s/(([^,]*,){4})([^,]+)(.*)/echo \x27\1\x27$(date -d "\3" +%s)\x27\4\x27/e'
```

or (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62862416)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1{$5=mktime(gensub(/[:\/]/, " ", "g", $5))} 1'
```

---

**Note:** For the `sed` solution, if the input can come from outside source, you'll have to take care to avoid malicious intent as mentioned in the comments. One way is to match the fifth column using `[0-9: -]+` or similar.

Comment: I suggest you to check the fifth field against `"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"` (or any regex to filter out the `$(.*)` and backticks). Otherwise, some malicious command could be executed if that fields contained `$(malicious command)`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin good point, but I'll leave it as todo for OP.. also, that could be simplified to `[0-9: -]+` as the aim is to avoid malicious command, any other syntax issue will be covered by the data command

Comment: @Jufo84 I've added alternate version, but in future please use correct format while asking the question.. if you missed something and question has to be changed which breaks existing answers, ask a new question

Comment: @Sundeep I corrected and it's okay: sed -Ei '2,$ s/(([^,]*,){4})([^,]+)(.*)/echo \x27\1\x27$(date -d "\3" +%s)\x27\4\x27/e' data.log

Comment: That's going to spawn separate processes to call `date` once per input line - that's extremely inefficient and since it requires GNU sed that means you also have access to GNU awk and so can us it's built-in time functions. Also, it's vulnerable to malicious code injection (try adding a line where the 5th field is `"$(ls)"`) and variable expansion (try setting it to `"$HOME"`).

Comment: @EdMorton the malicious part is mentioned at the end of the answer.. and yeah, GNU awk is better suited here..  also, do note that OP changed input requirements (see deleted answer)

Comment: Ah, I missed that, thanks for mentioning it. Well, no matter what the OP decides to do, hopefully others reading this in future will understand that you can do this job orders of magnitude faster and more robustly with GNU awk than with GNU sed.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}
{
    n=split($5,a,/[-" :]/)
    if(n==8)
        $5="\"" mktime(sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s %s",a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7])) "\""
}1' file
```

Output:

```
"Weight","Impedance","Units","User","Timestamp","PhysiqueRating"
"58.75","5.33","kg","7","1594484969","5"
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for gensub() and mktime():

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} NR>1{$10=mktime(gensub(/[-:]/," ","g",$10))} 1' file
"Weight","Impedance","Units","User","Timestamp","PhysiqueRating"
"58.75","5.33","kg","7","1594513769","5"
```